# How is the divine tree still there in episode 467 of Naruto Shippuden?

Tags: naruto

The divine tree eventually becomes the ten tails, and the ten tails gets split into the tailed beasts. So, the divine tree is basically the tailed beasts.

But, how is the divine tree still there in episode 467 of *Naruto Shippuden*?

Comment: anything else I can help you with?

Answer (score 1):

Episode 467 is a flashback episode, where Asura and others go discover about what the God Tree really is.

So there is no reason why the God Tree shouldn't exist, as this episode happens many thousands of years in the past.